# FlexiGrid "No Items", response clearly shows data

Tags: jquery, ajax, vb.net, flexigrid

Table is visible, looks fine, column headers show up, but after a split second of "processing, please wait..."  the status goes to "No Items".  Inspecting the response in the DOM shows the data is being returned properly from the web service, formatted as follows:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<MyDataClass xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns="http://tempuri.org/">
  <Page>1</Page>
  <Rows>
    <MyDataRow>
      <request_id>13073</request_id>
      <status>501</status>
      <req_by_user_id>herbjm</req_by_user_id>
    </MyDataRow>
    ...
    ....
  </Rows>
</MyDataClass>
```

Here is the flexigrid javascript in question:

```
$('#report').flexigrid({
    url: 'reportdata.asmx/rptPendingServerRequestsFlexi',
    dataType: 'xml',
    colModel: [
        { display: 'ID', name: 'request_id', width: 40, sortable: true, align: 'center' },
        { display: 'Status', name: 'status', width: 180, sortable: true, align: 'left' },
        { display: 'Requested By', name: 'req_by_user_id', width: 120, sortable: true, align: 'left' }
    ],
    searchitems: [
        { display: 'ID', name: 'request_id' },
        { display: 'Status', name: 'status', isdefault: true },
        { display: 'Requested By', name: 'req_by_user_id' }
    ],
    sortname: "request_id",
    sortorder: "desc",
    usepager: false,
    title: 'Server Requests',
    useRp: false,
    rp: 30,
    showTableToggleBtn: false,
    singleSelect: true
});
```

And for bonus points, how can I show the footer even if paging is diabled?

**UPDATE:** I inspected the DOM for the flexigrid demo and here is how their returned XML is formatted:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<rows>
    <page>1</page>
    <total>239</total>
    <row id='1'>
        <cell>1</cell>
        <cell>501</cell>
        <cell>Steve</cell>
    </row>
    <row id='2'>
        <cell>2</cell>
        <cell>501</cell>
        <cell>Fred</cell>
    </row>
</rows>
```

I'm guessing that's why it's not working?  To see how I'm building the response, please see this question: [vb.net return json object with multiple types?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14203171/vb-net-return-json-object-with-multiple-types/14205299#14205299)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to various information I have found [here](http://www.kenthouse.com/blog/2009/07/fun-with-flexigrids/) and a couple of other locations, flexigrid requires the XML to have specific format:

```
rows - the row definition
  page - the current page number
  total - the total count of rows in this collection
  row - the row, with a unique property called id
    cell - each row must contain cells in the order that they are displayed on the grid
```

Since the MyDataClass was generated as a result of [your previous question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14203171/vb-net-return-json-object-with-multiple-types/), here are updated versions of those classes that will produce the desired output:

```
<XmlType("rows")> _
Public Class MyDataClass

    <XmlElement("page")> _
    Public Property Page As Integer

    <XmlElement("total")> _
    Public ReadOnly Property Total As Integer
        Get
            If Me.Rows IsNot Nothing Then
                Return Me.Rows.Count
            Else
                Return 0
            End If
        End Get
    End Property
    <XmlElement("row")> _
    Public Property Rows As List(Of MyDataRow)

    ' Parameterless constructor to support serialization.
    Public Sub New()
        Me.Rows = New List(Of MyDataRow)
    End Sub
    Public Sub New(wPage As Integer, ds As DataSet)
        Me.New()

        Me.Page = wPage

        For Each oRow As DataRow In ds.Tables(0).Rows
            Dim oMyRow As New MyDataRow

            oMyRow.Id = CInt(oRow("id"))
            oMyRow.Name = CStr(oRow("Name"))

            Me.Rows.Add(oMyRow)
        Next

    End Sub
End Class

<XmlType("row")> _
Public Class MyDataRow
    <XmlAttribute("id")> _
    Public Property Id As Integer

    Private m_cCells As List(Of MyDataCell)

    <XmlIgnore()> _
    Public WriteOnly Property Name As String
        Set(value As String)
            Me.AddCell("Name", value)
        End Set
    End Property

    <XmlElement("cell")> _
    Public ReadOnly Property Cells As List(Of MyDataCell)
        Get
            Return m_cCells
        End Get
    End Property

    ' Parameterless constructor to support serialization
    Public Sub New()
        m_cCells = New List(Of MyDataCell)
    End Sub

    Public Sub AddCell(sCellName As String, sCellValue As String)
        m_cCells.Add(New MyDataCell(sCellName, sCellValue))
    End Sub
End Class

Public Class MyDataCell
    <XmlIgnore()> _
    Public Property Name As String
    <XmlText()> _
    Public Property Value As String

    ' Parameterless constructor to support serialization
    Public Sub New()

    End Sub
    Public Sub New(sCellName As String, sCellValue As String)
        Me.New()
        Me.Name = sCellName
        Me.Value = sCellValue
    End Sub
End Class
```

Comment: Yeah, and now I can't figure out how to adapt what you posted in my last question to fix it :D

Comment: Sweet!  I had to change total to a property just like page because it wasn't showing up in the XML, but it's working now.  I still have some kinks to work out, but I'm actually getting data!  Thanks Again!

Comment: I also had to add set/end set for request_id as it wasn't creating a cell, only the row id.  Thanks for leaving a couple gaps, makes me feel like I'm not totally useless :)

Answer (score 0):

Guys have a look of this demo of flexiuigrid

http://flexidemo.ranjitjena.com/