# Index was out of range while accessing list count

Tags: c#, json, linq, asp.net-mvc-4

I am facing very strange scenario. i have a list of customer and on the basis of some condition i am filtering that list. for example if user search for email i filter it out to get records matches which particular email. Also i am calculating paging as well which works well in case of first page 1. but when i try to give it 2 page it gives me strange behavior.  first look into the code below .

For page 1 this line of code works well

```
int total = _customerlist.Count();
```

but when i have second page in parameter it gives me "Index was out of range. Must be non-negative and less than the size of the collection." error. however i still have records in both cases 10 records in page 1 and 5 records in page 2. so when i get this error i have 5 records in "_customerlist"
why i am not getting this error when i have page 1?

Controller

```
public ActionResult CustomerList(int page, int rp, string sortname, string sortorder, string qtype, string query)
    {
        var _customerlist = _customerRepository.Table;

        if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(qtype) && !string.IsNullOrEmpty(query))
        {
            if (qtype == "Email")
            {
               _customerlist =  _customerlist.Where(p => p.Email.Contains(query));
            }
            else if (qtype == "LastName")
            {
                _customerlist = _customerlist.Where(p => p.LastName.Contains(query));
            }
            else if (qtype == "FirstName")
            {
                _customerlist = _customerlist.Where(p => p.FirstName.Contains(query));
            }
            else if (qtype == "Age")
            {
                _customerlist = _customerlist.Where(p => p.Age.ToString().Contains(query));
            }
            else if (qtype == "Sex")
            {
                _customerlist = _customerlist.Where(p => p.Sex.ToString().Contains(query));
            }
            else if (qtype == "Email")
            {
                _customerlist = _customerlist.Where(p => p.Email.ToString().Contains(query));
            }
            else if (qtype == "MembershipType")
            {
                _customerlist = _customerlist.Where(p => p.MembershipType.ToString().Contains(query));
            }
        }

        _customerlist = _customerlist.Skip((page - 1) * rp).Take(rp);

        int total = _customerlist.Count();

        return CreateFlexiJson(_customerlist, page, total);
    }


    private JsonResult CreateFlexiJson(IEnumerable<CustomerPartRecord> items, int page, int total)
    {            

        List<Object> rows = new List<Object>();            

        foreach (var item in items)
        {
            var familystring = string.Empty;

            if (item.MembershipType == "Family")
            {
                var familymembers = from p in _familyRepository.Table.Where(p => p.UserId == item.Email) select p;
                int i = 1;

                foreach (var familyitem in familymembers)
                {
                    if (i == 1)
                    {                            
                        familystring = familystring + "<label style=\"" + "color:#2B3856;font-weight: bold;" + "\">" + item.FirstName + " " + item.LastName + " (Head)</label>";

                        familystring = familystring + "<hr>" + "</hr>";

                        familystring = familystring + "<label style=\"" + "color:#2B3856;" + "\">" + familyitem.FirstName + " " + familyitem.LastName + "</label>";
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        familystring = familystring + "<label style=\"" + "color:#2B3856;" + "\">" + familyitem.FirstName + " " + familyitem.LastName + "</label>";


                    }

                    i++;
                }
            }
            else
            {
                familystring = "N/A";
            }

            rows.Add(new
            {
                id = item.Id,
                cell = new string[] {                   
                item.Id.ToString(), 
                item.FirstName, 
                item.LastName,
                item.Email,
                item.HouseNameOrNumber,
                item.Street,                    
                item.County,                    
                item.Town,                    
                item.Age.ToString(),                    
                item.Sex,
                item.BCUMembershipNumber,
                item.MembershipType,
                item.PostCode,
                item.HomePhone,
                item.MobilePhone,
                item.DOB,
                item.EmergencyContactName,
                item.EmergencyContactAddress,
                item.EmergencyContactPhone,
                item.EmergencyContactMobile,
                item.EmergencyContactEmail,    
                item.CreatedUtc.ToShortDateString(),
                String.Format(familystring),
                String.Format("<a href=" + "'" + "Member/More?UserId=" + item.Email + "'" + ">View</a>")  ,  
            }
            });


        }

        var result = new { page = page, total = total, rows = rows };

        return Json(result);

    }
```

cshtml

```
     $('#CustomerList').flexigrid({
            url: '@Url.Action("CustomerList", "Customer")',
            dataType: 'json',
            colModel: [
                {
                    display: 'Id',
                    name: 'Id',
                    width: 150,
                    sortable: true,
                    align: 'left',
                    hide: true
                },
                {
                    display: 'First Name',
                    name: 'FirstName',
                    width: 80,
                    sortable: true,
                    align: 'left'
                },
                {
                    display: 'Last Name',
                    name: 'LastName',
                    width: 80,
                    sortable: true,
                    align: 'left'
                },
                {
                    display: 'Email',
                    name: 'Email',
                    width: 140,
                    sortable: true,
                    align: 'left'
                },
                {
                    display: 'HouseNameOrNumber',
                    name: 'HouseNameOrNumber',
                    width: 200,
                    sortable: true,
                    align: 'left',
                    hide: true
                },
                {
                    display: 'Street',
                    name: 'Street',
                    width: 200,
                    sortable: true,
                    align: 'left',
                    hide: true                        
                },
                {
                    display: 'County',
                    name: 'County',
                    width: 200,
                    sortable: true,
                    align: 'left',
                    hide: true
                },
                {
                    display: 'Town',
                    name: 'Town',
                    width: 200,
                    sortable: true,
                    hide: true,
                    align: 'left'
                },
                {
                    display: 'Age',
                    name: 'Age',
                    width: 30,
                    sortable: true,
                    align: 'left'                        
                },
                {
                    display: 'Sex',
                    name: 'Sex',
                    width: 30,
                    sortable: true,                        
                    align: 'left'
                },
                {
                    display: 'B.C.U',
                    name: 'BCUMembershipNumber',
                    width: 60,
                    sortable: true,                        
                    align: 'left'
                },
                {
                    display: 'Membership Type',
                    name: 'MembershipType',
                    width: 100,
                    sortable: true,                        
                    align: 'left'
                },
                {
                    display: 'Post Code',
                    name: 'PostCode',
                    width: 100,
                    sortable: true,
                    align: 'left',
                    hide: true,
                },
                {
                    display: 'Home Phone',
                    name: 'HomePhone',
                    width: 100,
                    sortable: true,
                    align: 'left',
                    hide: true,
                },
                {
                    display: 'Mobile Phone',
                    name: 'MobilePhone',
                    width: 100,
                    sortable: true,
                    align: 'left',
                    hide: true,
                },
                {
                    display: 'DOB',
                    name: 'DOB',
                    width: 100,
                    sortable: true,
                    align: 'left',
                    hide:true
                },

                {
                    display: 'EmergencyContactName',
                    name: 'EmergencyContactName',
                    width: 100,
                    sortable: true,
                    align: 'left',
                    hide:true
                },

                {
                    display: 'EmergencyContactAddress',
                    name: 'EmergencyContactAddress',
                    width: 100,
                    sortable: true,
                    align: 'left',
                    hide:true
                },
                {
                    display: 'EmergencyContactPhone',
                    name: 'EmergencyContactPhone',
                    width: 100,
                    sortable: true,
                    align: 'left',
                    hide:true
                },
                {
                    display: 'EmergencyContactMobile',
                    name: 'EmergencyContactMobile',
                    width: 100,
                    sortable: true,
                    align: 'left',
                    hide:true
                },
                {
                    display: 'EmergencyContactEmail',
                    name: 'EmergencyContactEmail',
                    width: 100,
                    sortable: true,
                    align: 'left',
                    hide:true
                },
                {
                    display: 'Member Since',
                    name: 'CreatedUtc',
                    width: 70,
                    sortable: true,
                    align: 'left',                        
                },
                {
                    display: 'Family',
                    name: '',
                    width: 150,
                    sortable: true,
                    align: 'left'
                },
                {
                    display: 'Other Info.',
                    name: '',
                    width: 50,
                    sortable: true,
                    align: 'left'                        
                }

            ],
            buttons: [
            {
                name: 'Edit',
                bclass: 'edit',
                onpress: test
            }, {
                name: 'Delete',
                bclass: 'delete',
                onpress: test
            }, {
                separator: true
            }],
            searchitems: [
                {
                display: 'First Name',
                name: 'FirstName'
                },
                {
                    display: 'Last Name',
                    name: 'LastName'
                },
                {
                    display: 'Email',
                    name: 'Email'
                },
                {
                    display: 'Age',
                    name: 'Age'
                },
                {
                    display: 'Sex',
                    name: 'Sex'
                },
                {
                    display: 'Membership Type',
                    name: 'MembershipType'
                }

            ],
            sortname: "LastName",
            sortorder: "asc",
            usepager: true,
            title: 'Customer',
            useRp: true,
            rp: 10,
            showTableToggleBtn: true,
            width: 920,
            height: 500,
            singleSelect: true
        });
```

Comment: Are you pulling it to Gridview or anything else..? what is that control..

Comment: i am using jquery Flexigrid

Comment: your code is not complete, please complete it to be able to help

Comment: i have added a cshtml code for flexigrid.and also some code for controller.

Comment: Is `page` zero-based? In which line does the exception occur? You should check that `page - 1` doesn't get negative.

Comment: please refer this [FlexiGrid Paging][1] 

  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11873509/flexigrid-not-paging

Comment: i have clearly mentioned when page = 2 . i get this error.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Try to use Dynamic Linq

1. [Dynamic WHERE clause in LINQ](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/848415/dynamic-where-clause-in-linq)
2. https://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/vstudio/bb894665.aspx